# multivariate random forest with opencv

Tags: opencv, machine-learning, random-forest

Let's say we are trying to classify a pencil as healthy or not and we have two variables for this purpose: length and weight of the pencil. Now, what should I give to the training method of random forest implemented in opencv? I am really confused with this because I have two different data, both of them are numeric but their units are different. Below example will give a better sense:

```
Height (cm)   Weight (gr)   Healthy? (bool)
-----------   -----------   ---------------
10            34            0
4             6             0
12            14            1
8             20            1
5             18            0
```

If I train a univariate random forest with only height, {10, 4, 12, 8, 5} and {0, 0, 1, 1, 0} vectors will be the parameters. However, what if I want to use both variables, what will be the parameters?

Comment: It is not clear what are you asking. Of course you'd want to use both of your variables in the classification...

Comment: I want to use both but how? For example, I need a function which takes a height and a weight and produces a value, so that I can give this value to the training function. Right?

Comment: 0r should I concatenate features and give the training algorithm a vector whose size is 2 x sampleCount?

Comment: Yeah, I don't know exactly about how it is implemented in C, but in Python 2d list should work...

Comment: I got it. I will give a training data matrice like this: [(10,34), (4,6), (12,14), (8,20), (5,18)] and a class vector like this: {0, 0, 1, 1, 0} then the classifier will handle this as a multi variable data sample. @sashkello I will accept your answer if you write an answer. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Python the training data input can be fed into as a list of tuples, if you have multiple variables.

Comment: The reason of my confusion was images. While we are using images as training data we give every pixel of a single image as a separate feature.